# what does the error message from hg convert mean?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

i am trying to use hg convert to delete specific public files and create new repo.

the commands throws an error at a particular revision. this is the error message. please let me know what this is about and how can i resolve this.

```
#!python
** Mercurial version (4.6.1).  TortoiseHg version (4.6.1)
** Command: 
** CWD: C:\WINDOWS\system32
** Encoding: cp1252
** Extensions loaded: fetch, keyword, strip, mq, purge, rebase, shelve, split, convert, tortoisehg.util.configitems
** Python version: 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Windows version: sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=2, build=9200, platform=2, service_pack='')
** Processor architecture: x64
** Qt-5.9.2 PyQt-5.9.1 QScintilla-2.10.2.dev1711012104
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\repowidget.pyo", line 889, in onRevisionSelected
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\revdetails.pyo", line 307, in onRevisionSelected
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\revdetails.pyo", line 328, in _setContextToFileList
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\manifestmodel.pyo", line 289, in setRev
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\manifestmodel.pyo", line 403, in _repopulateNodes
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\manifestmodel.pyo", line 431, in _populateNodes
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\manifestmodel.pyo", line 604, in _populaterepo
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\manifestmodel.pyo", line 634, in _populatesubrepos
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1437, in __get__
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 166, in substate
  File "mercurial\subrepoutil.pyo", line 61, in state
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 1088, in data
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1437, in __get__
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 702, in _filenode
  File "mercurial\filelog.pyo", line 54, in lookup
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1494, in lookup
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1416, in _match
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 812, in rev
WdirUnsupported
```

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version of Mercurial?  Its up to 6.1.4, maybe you have an newer HG repository that is not compatible with version 4.6.1 ?  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads

Comment: yes, i have tried two newer versions -  6.2rc and 6.1.4 and getting same error with both.